# Embedding interactive map maker in external website

Tags: google-maps, arcgis-online

I'm currently developing a new website that will allow users to submit project proposals via an online form for assessment and feedback. The system is currently working well, but I'd like to extend it to allow people to submit spatial information as part of their project submissions (it's for global landscape projects). Within the current form, I'd like users to be able to create maps either from fresh or via upload of existing spatial data that they can then save and submit.

I have access to ArcGIS Online and ideally would like to embed the map creation functionality within my form on my external site that is then saved and submitted, however I'm not sure if this is possible?

I've read through the API documentation but couldn't spot anything that describes embedding in external sites. I'm also open to using alternatives such as embedding Google Map Maker (if possible?), but I'm guessing this will run into problems where each form user will require a Google account and be pre-authenticated somehow before submitting the form (a big disadvantage).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve such a task?

Comment: Google Map Maker has Closed: https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder and embed that on your page:

Widget for adding data to the map: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-add-data.htm

Embed the app: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012322